# The Active Record

Tags: records

I have a question on Craft's Active Record,

```
 protected function defineAttributes(){
        'customer_ref' => array(
            AttributeType::String,
            'required' => true
        ), 
        'fault_code' => array(
            AttributeType::String,
            'required' => true
        ),
        'supplier_agent' => array(
            AttributeType::String,
            'required' => true
        ), 
        'response_delay' => array(
            AttributeType::String,
            'required' => true
        ) 
}
```

I have my defined attributes method, when I set `required = true`, and the field is empty the record fails to save!

When I set it as required = false (or just not add the required part) , the record will save but none of the field values get inserted to the database, I have a blank row.

So what do i do, I just want it to insert the row, if there is something missing let it be missing!

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the web:

```
 public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('customer_name,customer_email', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
    );
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850081/how-can-i-set-a-date-to-null-in-yii

has fixed my issue.

thanks!