# Record - Mixed/String values will not be saved if attribute not required=true

Tags: plugins, records, attribute

I have defined string and mixed attributes for my Record/Model.

```
'titel' => array(AttributeType::String),
'lage' => array(AttributeType::Mixed, 'required' => true),
```

If i try to save a record, the data will not be saved, if required=true is not defined! That happens with both, string and mixed attribute types.

But i want to save the records also with empty values.
Whats wrong?

// UPDATE:

I found this [The Active Record](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/the-active-record) and added this to my model

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('title', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
    );
}
```

But it doesnt change anything.

Comment: After you call `$yourRecord->save()`, does `$yourRecord->getErrors()` return anything?

Comment: No, no errors at all. The log file shows that db Commands will be executed and the relevant values are definitely null. As soon as i change 'required' to true, the same values will be saved.

Comment: There is something critically wrong with Craft here.  Amateur hour.